# As redshift increases are there more large galaxies from mergers because there was less dark energy in the past?

Tags: galaxy, dark-energy

Dark energy moves galaxies apart.Is this reflected in an increasing number of large galaxies as redshift increases and dark energy decreases?

Answer (score 5):

The merger rate was indeed larger in the past, i.e. at higher redshifts. However, this is not due the smaller density of dark energy (since this only started dominating relatively recently, and only does so on scales larger than gravitationally bound structures), but simply because the Universe hadn't expanded so much, so galaxies were closer together.

Moreover, once galaxies have merged, they don't "unmerge". Hence there cannot be more larger galaxies at higher redshifts (in principle you could have more small galaxies forming at late time, thereby reducing the fraction of massive galaxies, but that doesn't happen; in fact smaller galaxies tend to form at earlier times, in the so-called "hierarchical structure formation").

#### Minor vs. major merging

Merging can be divided into minor and major merging, depending on the ratio between the merging galaxies' mass. Major merging involves galaxies of comparable masses and can be quite violent, whereas minor merging are of more "accretion-like" nature. The following figure (from [O'Leary et al. 2021](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021MNRAS.501.3215O/abstract)) shows how the rate of major mergers (here defined as a mass ratio of $>0.25$) increases for various halo masses with redshift, as predicted by the empirical galaxy formation model EMERGE:

[image: major]

For convenience, I annotated the lookback time in gigayears. Dark energy only started dominating at redshift $z\simeq0.3$ (marked by "Λ ~ M"), some 3½ Gyr ago.

Similar trends are seen for minor mergers, e.g. in this plot (from [Rodriguez-Gomez et al. 2015](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015MNRAS.449...49R/abstract)) showing the merger rates in the cosmological simulation Illustris:

[image: minor]

The dark blue line in the latter plot shows major merging, whereas "greener" colors show successively minor-er mergers. Black lines show predictions from a fitting function from [Genel et al. (2010)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...719..229G/abstract).

#### Dry vs. wet merging

Another way to divide merging is according to whether the two merging galaxies are gas-rich or gas-poor, called "wet" and "dry" merging, respectively. Whereas wet merging tends to trigger star formation and quasar activity, dry merging is typically less dramatic. Merging can also be "mixed", involving a gas-rich and a gas-poor galaxy, which may shut down star formation in the gas-rich one. The following plot (from [Lin et al. 2008](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008ApJ...681..232L/abstract)) shows how the fraction of wet mergers was larger in the past, at the expense of dry/mixed mergers (the data points are observations and the lines are a semi-analytical model from [Khochfar & Burkert 2003](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003ApJ...597L.117K/abstract)):

[image: wetdry]

This evolution reflects how galaxies in general were more gas-rich in the past, whereas at late times the fraction of red, gas-poor galaxies has increased.

Comment: Why was the fraction of wet mergers higher in the past compared to dry mergers Is this because wet galaxies had stronger gravitational attraction for one another.

Comment: @DaveTheWave No, it's mostly because galaxies in general were more gas-rich in the past. With time, the galaxies use their gas to form more and more stars, and while massive stars quickly return their gas to the interstellar medium, the bulk of the stars formed are small and hence long-lived. Some galaxies also lose their gas, either by intense starbursts or quasar activity blowing it out of the galaxy, or by being ripped out of the galaxies during merger events.

Comment: $\Lambda$ did not start to dominate on the scale of galaxy mergers at z=3.  It never dominates in a region with above closure density.

Comment: @eshaya No that's true. I can see that my answer gives that impression, so I removed that part. Thanks!

Comment: Downvote though?

Comment: @eshaya Though to be clear, dark energy still has an impact where it does not dominate, and it is indeed one influence on the merger rate today.

Comment: @Sten  The influence that dark energy has on merger rates is through weak coupling from its effects on very large scales where densities are low.  It is making large voids slightly bigger, so more matter in walls of voids and clusters, but walls are more stretched.   Its affect on whether 2 galaxies in a group will merge is negligible.

Comment: @eshaya Rough estimate: collapse (merging) happens around a factor of 2 in time later than turnaround (farthest separation of the two galaxies). For objects merging today, that would put turnaround around redshift 0.8, when dark energy was 40% as dense as matter. At turnaround, the system's average matter density is ~6 times the mean, so dark energy would contribute around 40%/6=7% as much energy density as the system's matter. Its repulsion would be around 14% of the matter's attraction (with the factor of 2 arising from the pressure contribution). Is a 14% effect negligible?

Comment: To be clear, dark energy isn't *preventing* mergers. It's delaying them, which reduces the merger rate.

Comment: Galaxy mergers today are not happening from turnaround, generally.  Field galaxies are rare and at very very low densities.  Galaxies move around in a group potential and eventually bump into another galaxy.  Perhaps you are looking at halo statistics from N-body calculations, which means you are looking at groups merging with one another or more precisely matter falling into halos/groups.  Hardly any of this is expected in the next Hubble Time.

Comment: @eshaya I actually didn't interpret the question as "could dark energy rip galaxies apart", but more along the lines of "could dark energy move them so far apart today that the merger rate is smaller". But I see that it could also be interpreted as the former.

Comment: I deleted my comment.  I see now that many think a region of space collapses and the material in it mergers to form a galaxy.  This is oversimplified, but it leads to the question, now that dark energy dominates will it truncate collapsing regions?  And, why wouldn’t galaxies forming by collapse therefore be smaller now?

Comment: @eshaya Yes, I'm thinking more about halo mergers. For objects within already virialized structures, dark energy would be a percent-level contribution today.